# access c++ objects from another file in Arduino

Tags: c++, class, arduino, external

In my Arduino file, TimerTest.ino

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Pulse.h"
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

elapsedMillis timeElapsed ; 
Pulse trigger(45,60) ; //45 is pin number, 60 is pulse interval in msec
```

When I defined Pulse.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Pulse.h"

Pulse::Pulse(int pin, long interval)
{
  _pin = pin ;
  pinMode(_pin, OUTPUT);
  _interval = interval);
}

void Pulse::PulseOut()
{
  if(timeElapsed > _previousTime + _interval)
    digitalWrite(_pin,LOW);
}
```

I got a compiler error saying that timeElapsed is not in this scope of this file,
I don't know enough c++ to understand the access mechanism, can somebody point me to the right solution.

Comment: If you must use global variables, add an `extern` declaration for your global variable into a header file and include that header file.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your global variable `elapsedMillis timeElapsed;` in your sketch, it is only visible to that file, and not to other files.

In Pulse.cpp, after the includes, you can add the statements

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

extern elapsedMillis timeElapsed;
```

That tells the C++ compiler that there is a global variable that is defined in another file, that you want to use from this file. The compiler will then know not to allocate new storage for it, but instead it makes a placeholder for it, that it will glue together during the linking phase, pointing to the storage created in the sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not such a great idea, in general.

Depending on what else you want to do with the Pulse class and timeElapsed, you have various options:

- pass timeElapsed as parameter to the constructor
- pass timeElapsed as parameter to PulseOut
- make timeElapsed a field of the Pulse object (public or private with getter/setters)
- not use OOP at all: if you are more familiar with C, stick to it and you will have better chances to produce code that works as you want and is easier to debug. IMHO Arduino is not the best choice to learn OOP, as it makes debugging much harder than a typical OOP learning path that relies on programming just a normal PC.

Comment: You should always use whatever makes your code easier to understand and maintain. Global variables are ok when used judiciously, such as in small programs like test programs or examples. Arduino sketches are often small enough that global variables don't become overly problematic. However, when programs start growing larger, global variables become much harder to keep track of, making your code obtuse and harder to maintain.  Just be smart about your choice to use them.

Comment: "Judiciously" is highly subjective. And I doubt anybody tries to not be smart, intentionally. A class accessing a global variable is suspicious, at best.

But, most important, the C++ compiler can be an invaluable ally in turning runtime bugs into compiletime errors.

Using global variables and similarly relaxed approach blunts the usefulness of the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally got the pulse class working but it turns out to be a lot more messy than I thought and I'm still not too sure how the code